# How does pet dog ownership vary (if at all) in western countries by ethnicity?

Tags: dogs

For example, is there a significant difference in the prevalence of pet dog ownership in the United States among the white, black and Hispanic populations, or in Britain among the White British, Black British and British Pakistani populations?

Please note that I am asking only about pet dogs, not about dogs kept principally for personal protection or other work.

Comment: This question has a major focus on sociology (habitus, culture, distinction) rather than pet care. However, there's unfortunately no good other SE site for it. I'm voting to close it as off-topic because and because it's very likely to attract a lot of questions how to interpret your question in the context of pet care.

Comment: There is nothing in the advice here that stipulates that questions about pets should only be about care for pets. This q is about pets and so it is on-topic. Despite your fears, it has not attracted any questions whatsoever about interpretation either in the context of care or in any other context. The only answer it has had was supplied by someone who needed no help regarding interpretation and was direct and to the point. The reason I asked the q was precisely to get an answer, and I have now got one, so I am happy to delete this obviously on-topic q (and my account) if you ask me to.

Comment: I think this question works here. While a large amount of questions are about care on this site, this one is just as much about pets. And it is a good and clear question, that has no obvious better site to be asked.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, it seems that **the rate of pet dog ownership is more than twice as high among white people than among black people, and nearly twice as high as it is among people of Hispanic ethnicity**. A survey of 3014 respondents conducted by Pew in that country in 2005 ([source](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2006/03/07/gauging-family-intimacy/63-2/), [full report](http://assets.pewresearch.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2010/10/Pets.pdf)) found that the percentages of respondents with each of the three ethnicities who had a dog were as follows:

```
white    45%
Hispanic 26%
black    20%
```

The differences do not seem to be explicable purely by income inequality, since the figures for income brackets were as follows:

```
$100000+       50%
$50000-$99999  44%
$30000-$49999  42%
$0-$29999      29%
```

Note that the researchers asked specifically about pets, not about dogs kept exclusively for other purposes.